# Should I set the `l1-cache-size` and `l2-cache-size` param in gcc on my own?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I saw in the maunals of `gcc`, that you can add the arguments `--param l1-cache-size=<num>` and `--param l2-cache-size=<num>` to `gcc`. Is it recommended to set them if you know that:

1. the program will only run on your system
2. you know the sizes of both caches

or does `gcc` set them to an appropriate value on its own?

Comment: If your program will only run on your system, I'd hope that `-march=native` (which implies `-mtune=native`) would take care of setting those to the values for your system.  Or if cross-compiling, `-march=icelake-server` for example should use the right values for that Xeon.  The use-case would be tweaking this tuning setting with tune=generic, or maybe to change GCC's decision-making if it made a decision which was actually sub-optimal for your machine with those cache sizes.  But I haven't played with these options so I'm not sure.